# Confusion about curve, genus, and rational point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The question I am supposed to solve:

Consider a smooth projective curve with function field $\mathbb{F}_{7}(x,y)$ where $y^{2}=x^{6}+5$. Find the genus, and and the number of rational points.

I thought I solved the problem, but now I realized that different method is giving me different result. I am not sure what is going on here, so can someone point out the error.

Note that we have the factorization $x^{6}+5=(x^{3}-3)(x^{3}+3)$. Now this is a degree $2$ extension of the rational function field, and it can only be ramified at at most $3$ points, so in fact it ramifies at $2$ points, and the genus is $1$.

On the other hand, a curve with this function field is $Y^{2}Z^{4}=X^{6}+5Z^{6}$ where the function are $x:[X:Y:Z]\rightarrow[X:Z]$ and $y:[X:Y:Z]\rightarrow[Y:Z]$. By the degree-genus formula we get genus $10$.

Now for rational point, from the equation $Y^{2}Z^{4}=X^{6}+5Z^{6}$ we see that there is a rational point $[X:Y:Z]=[0:1:0]$. On the other hand, this means that the function $x$ send $[0:1:0]$ to $[0:0]$ which is not an actual point on $\mathbb{P}_{1}$.

I am afraid I have a deep misunderstanding here. Can anyone help?

Comment: There seem to be a few issues with your genus calculations. First, using Riemann-Hurwitz to calculate the genus requires that you use the projective model. Observe that plugging $Z=0$ into your projective equation yields $X^6 = 0$, so you seem to have additional ramification at infinity. What's more, why do you claim that there are at most $3$ ramification points? Your equation suggests more like $6$. Finally, note that the degree-genus formula in $\mathbb P^2$ only holds for smooth curves.

Comment: @TabesBridges: it doesn't look like it has any rational points, so it should be smooth by default isn't it? and what about my argument with the rational points?

Comment: I mostly work over $\mathbb C$; I'm not sure what rational points have to do with smoothness. What definition are you using? Hartshorne says that a $k$-scheme is smooth if it remains regular after base-changing to the algebraic closure, so I would expect rational points to be irrelevant.

Comment: @TabesBridges: ah thank you, I see now. Looks like I copied all the theorems verbatim from the $\mathbb{C}$ case and expect it to work the same way for finite field. Guess I would need to look up a different book.